# Delay and wake up a task from being executed? (Task.Delay?)

Tags: c#, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, task, scheduling

I have a situation where I have multiple threads being executed at once. In some cases these threads will be put in a while() loop for an unknown amount of time, and if a certain number of threads get caught in this loop then eventually the scheduler stops letting other threads be executed.

I was wondering if there is some way I could delay a thread from being executed (remove it from the scheduled list) and then let other threads in. Is it then possible to wake up that thread later by a threadID or something like that?

I am reading about Task.Delay and see it suspends execution from a timespan and that it is possible to time something out for an infinite amount of time, but is it possible to time it out indefinitely UNTIL a event occurs and then undelay it by some name or ID?

Edit: I thought this question was one that was harder to post code for, but more or less I have a situation where requests come in and are put into a loop like:

```
while(true){
  //check for something that could make me want to delete this thread/request
  //do some things 
 }
```

I had noticed that when I sent large number of requests that I never stopped ended up still in his loop (which I understand), but it seems the max amount of threads that could be doing this is 16/32 (depends on my computer that I run it on) and it is stopping other requests from being scheduled to run.

I wanted to know if inside the while() loop I could do something like this:

```
while(true){
     //put this thread to sleep
     //do some things that 
     //call some function to wake up the specific thread I need to do work on, before I put it back to sleep
 }
```

The difference in this now is that instead of 16/32 threads running I can have 1 "king thread" that enters this while() loop that can 'do some things' and then wake up the thread that needs to be affected by the 'things'. Is there a way to sleep and wake up a specific thread so that other threads can be scheduled to run?

Comment: Without code, it's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe [Monitor.Wait(Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateab679(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I added more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From the question I guess that you are running a busy waiting loop. That's pretty bad as you found out.

Make the loop wait for an event:

```
while (true) {
 WaitForEvent();
 DoWork();
}
```

This requires cooperation from the thread (or component) that makes the event happen. You could use a `ManualResetEvent` or a `TaskCompletionSource` to make this coordination happen.

I can't really be more specific because the question is not particularly concrete about the scenario. I hope this pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: So your saying make a async method that waits for events so threads get caught up there rather than looping over and over?

Comment: It doesn't have to be async but it should wait in some form.